# How to define table structure for storing logic gate data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I have table A with a bunch of rows and columns in sql. When accessing each row in code it is evaluated into true or false.

I want to make another table B which relates to rows in table A and defines a logic circuit.

So for example if I have table A with these rows

```
1  - true
2  - true
3  - false
4  - true
```

and I want to define a relation between a few rows like this: "(2 AND 3)" or "(2 AND (3 OR 4))" and save it in the table so that I could evaluate this data in the code later on. How would I achieve this?

I was thinking of a structure like this

```
id | firstValue | secondValue | operator
```

In this case each value could also be a row in table B to create more complex circuits. But how would I know which table to join on each value? Would I need another field to define which table i'm joining?

Maybe there is a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. It sounds like you want to store formulas as data and then execute those formulas? This requires dynamic sql and is not going to be an easy task. Perhaps if you could explain more clearly what you are trying to do we can help more.

Comment: I want to allow the user to define when is a certain feature active. He would have a bunch of blocks (rows in table A) which define parameters. He could then arrange those blocks in an AND/OR/XOR/etc circuit which is saved in DB. Then I would access this logic that the user has created to determine if something is active or not. Does that paint a picture?

Comment: How is the user going to interact with the database?   Through an application, or directly issuing SQL commands?

Comment: It paints a picture but I have no idea what the picture is. It is still fuzzy in my mind like the morning after a good night of drinking.

Comment: @Tab Alleman It would be a web interface, so the code could enter any data as long as it can be generated and parsed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're thinking of coding this, but here's the structure for TableB that I would start with:

```
CircuitID     TableARowID      Position
```

`CircuitID` + `Position` would be the Primary Key.   So to build each circuit, you evaluate each Table A Row associated with it in the order of `Position`  (ie:   Position 1 is evaluated first, then Position 2, etc).

This allows you to have any number of "blocks" from Table A associated with any given Circuit.